# Liferay 6.2. social office user bar and dockbar

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

In users' personal sites pages(/user/xx/so/dashboard), user bar and dockbar are not accessible from any user without the power user or administrator role. In every other site's page, users can normally access it without these 2 roles.
Why is this happening?

Comment: did you resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by creating a hook that assigns automatically the Power User role on every newly created user.

A Liferay staff member told me that Power User role is required for all social office plugins, sites etc. [liferay post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/43599406)